# Delete folder content and remove from version control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a folder on the SVN tree with a lot of garbage on it. We want to do the following:

- Delete folder content (leave the folder empty on the SVN)
- Ignore subsequents commits for the content of this folder.

The problem is that every developer working at this proyect, can write garbage into this folder, but it never be commited to the SVN. BUT, currently there is a lot of garbage on the SVN itself.

Because the folder is already on the SVN tree, we can't add a 'ignore' property.

Note that the content deleting must be done at the SVN tree. Local content of every developer' folder must be left untouched.

We work with Eclipse+Subclipse and TortoiseSVN.

So, any idea on how do this ?

Comment: Why is it that the only people who ever bother apologising for their bad English are the people with good English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've said, you can't add the `svn:ignore` property, and you can't delete the folder without that change being propagated to individual working directories.

Ultimately, you're trying to subvert the way Subversion works — instead, just ask your developers to back-up their copies of the directory, and then delete it from the repository in the usual way.

Comment: Finally we do this. Sorry, cant voteup you cause not enought reputation. Thanks!

Comment: @Juanjico: Hah, finally indeed! Glad you got your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Tortoise has an option for this. Right click on the folder and click "TortoiseSVN" then select "Delete and add to ignore list."

Comment: Thanks, but the folder must exists. We want to delete the content of folder, not the folder itself and prevent future commits of the new local folder content.

Comment: If you do "Delete and add to ignore list" you can then recreate the folder and svn won't add it...

Comment: @ed: Actually, _I_ downvoted you, and I did so because you did not answer the question that was posed.

Comment: Yeah didn't seem to notice the stuff about devel's folders needing to be untouched. Ho hum. I do wonder thought, if you apply that rule for downvoting then there'll be a lot of negative-voted answers out there...

Answer (score -1):

I'd faced same issue in similar setup, and I found it really tough. I managed to do this using the `svn` command line client (could be downloaded from [here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)).

```
cd directory-to-remove
svn remove *
svn commit -m "message deletion"
svn update
svn propset svn:ignore * .
svn commit -m "message ignoring"
```

After this command sequence directory-to-remove itself will stay on svn but anything inside this directory couldn't be committed to repository.

Comment: But you deleted everything inside it. That change will be propagated to all working dirs, no?

Comment: Yes, everything inside folder id deleted as you described in question
* Delete folder content (leave the folder empty on the SVN)
* Ignore subsequents commits for the content of this folder.

Please clarify "propagation to all working dirs".

Comment: It's stated in the question. "Note that the content deleting must be done at the SVN tree. **Local content of every developer' folder must be left untouched.**"